# VBoxManage error, network problems

Tags: facebook, vagrant, virtualbox, command-line-interface

I'm trying to set up [Facebook CTF](https://github.com/facebook/fbctf).

Here's my setup currently

**Host OS:** Ubuntu 14.04

**Virtualbox:** 4.3.10_Ubuntur93012

**Vagrant:** 1.8.3

When I change into the `fbctf` directory, and run `vagrant up`, I'm getting this output.

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "d357833b-56cf-44f6-bb74-e09d61a022c3", "--nic2", "none", "--nic3", "none", "--nic4", "none", "--nic5", "none", "--nic6", "none", "--nic7", "none", "--nic8", "none", "--nic9", "none", "--nic10", "none", "--nic11", "none", "--nic12", "none", "--nic13", "none", "--nic14", "none", "--nic15", "none", "--nic16", "none", "--nic17", "none", "--nic18", "none", "--nic19", "none", "--nic20", "none", "--nic21", "none", "--nic22", "none", "--nic23", "none", "--nic24", "none", "--nic25", "none", "--nic26", "none", "--nic27", "none", "--nic28", "none", "--nic29", "none", "--nic30", "none", "--nic31", "none", "--nic32", "none", "--nic33", "none", "--nic34", "none", "--nic35", "none", "--nic36", "none"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: No network adapter in slot 8 (total 8 adapters)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "GetNetworkAdapter(GetOptState.uIndex - 1, nic.asOutParam())" at line 1387 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the new 1.8.3 version ([GH-7417](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7417))

This has been addressed in [1.8.4](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) that has just been release, download and it should be fixed